# How to use Jekyll baseurl in css files

Tags: css, jekyll, base-url

I'm using Jekyll to host a site on Github pages.  The problem lies in referencing file paths within css files.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
body { {background: #FFF url('{{ site.baseurl}}/images/page_bg.JPG') center 0 no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; color: #4b595f; }
```

But it doesn't seem that Jekyll process the css files, so site.baseurl never gets swapped out.

There are other situations where I can't just change it to an inline style, so assume that's not a possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jekyll processes all files that have YAML front matter. Stick a front matter section (even if it's empty) at the beginning of your file, and Jekyll will transform it correctly. Try using this at the start of the file:

```
---
title: CSS stylesheet
---
```

Comment: FWIW, you can so leave out any content and do just 2 lines `---\n---` (sorry I can't make it look right in this comment field...).

Answer (score 18):

Using the trick from Brian Willis' answer won't work with SASS in `@import`-ed files.

Instead, you can do this:

`main.scss`

```
---
---
$baseurl: "{{ site.baseurl }}";
@import "myfile";
```

`_sass/_myfile.scss`

```
myclass {
  background: url($baseurl + "/my/image.svg");
}
```

---

Don't forget

- the quotes around `"{{ site.baseurl }}"` (important in case of empty `site.baseurl`, and probably more robust) and
- the plus sign with `$baseurl + "/my/image.svg"`.

Comment: Same issue will pop up with SASS. Same fix except put the value of the `$baseurl` variable into quotes and remove the semicolon. The quotes had me messed up for a bit.

Comment: Found a relevant article about some [weirdness with SASS strings](http://vanseodesign.com/css/sass-strings/). I think this answer will work perfectly without further reading. But if anyone is curious....

Comment: I would improve the `main.scss` a bit, use `$baseurl: "{% if site.baseurl != '/' %}{{ site.baseurl }}{% endif %}";` so you are even save when the baseurl is just a single slash. Otherwise you have // slashes in CSS-pathes

Answer (score 2):

The solutions proposed above didn't work for me ; main.scss cannot be processed without error if I add a front matter to it.

The solution for me was to use module configuration:

Defining a configurable variable at the very top of the main.scss file.
`main.scss`

```
$baseurl= "" !default;
...

@font-face {
  font-family: 'My_font';
  src: url($baseurl + "/assets/fonts/font_file.ttf");
}
```

Refer to the main file and pass the value for $baseurl
`_sass/my_file.scss`

```
---
---    
@use "main" with (
   $baseurl: "{{site.baseurl}}"
 );
```

Reference can be found [on the SaSS website](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables/#configuring-modules)